# Do different TLDs affect your search engine ranking?

Tags: domains, web-development, email, top-level-domains, bulk-email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google penalize .me or .tv sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/does-google-penalize-me-or-tv-sites)

I have two identical domain names with different suffixes `org` and `com`.

I just installed POSTFIX which has auto configured itself to the `.com` domain name but I generally use the `.org` tld based domain name as the primary (even the `.com` redirects to `.org`).

Which is better to use as `myhostname` and `mydomain` are there any advantages to using one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I think these two previous questions should help you out

- [SEO and alias domain names](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17476/seo-and-alias-domain-names)
- [Could I buy a domain name to increase traffic to my site like this?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/could-i-buy-a-domain-name-to-increase-traffic-to-my-site-like-this)